# confluent kafka to s3 connection failed with ERROR Unexpected exception in Thread[KafkaBasedLog Work Thread -

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I set up on EC2 the confluent (4.0) connector that reads from kafka and writes to S3.

The standalone try goes well:

bin/connect-standalone etc/standalone/example-connect-worker.properties etc/standalone/example-connect-s3-sink.properties

However the distributed version keeps failing with

```html
[2018-01-30 21:26:05,860] ERROR Unexpected exception in Thread[KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - connect-configs,5,main] (org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog:334)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer is not subscribed to any topics or assigned any partitions
 at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1097)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.poll(KafkaBasedLog.java:256)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.access$500(KafkaBasedLog.java:69)
 at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog$WorkThread.run(KafkaBasedLog.java:327)
```

I just wanted first use connector class equals FileStreamSinkConnector

The sink conf files goes like:

```html
name=local-file-sink
#connector.class=FileStreamSink
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
file=test.sink.txt
topics=tests3

s3.bucket=tests3
s3.prefix=tests3
s3.endpoint=http://localhost:9090
s3.path_style=true
local.buffer.dir=/tmp/connect-system-test
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the command I ran for distributed mode is ./bin/connect-distributed ./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties ./etc/kafka/connect-file-sink.properties and in ./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties I changed bootstrap.servers=my_kafka_host:9092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a distributed Connect worker with `./bin/connect-distributed` you may only supply the worker's properties through command line.

To load a connector by posting its config to the worker's REST endpoint you may use `curl` or an equivalent command.

For example:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @config.json http://localhost:8083/connectors`

where `config.json` is a file containing your connector's properties.

More info here: 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing.html#distributed-example